# IDE for libpurple (Pidgin)?

Tags: programming, pidgin, ide, libpurple

I'm interested to develop an app using pidgin & libpurple, but how can I "import" the code to some IDE that manages GTK?

someone use/is aware of one like that?

Answer (score 1):

The two that immediately come to my mind are [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) and [Anjuta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/).